# how to communicate to the same com port from multiple threads in python

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a thermal board in one com port, and one thread A in my python program try to constantly inquire the data (send the command to the thermal board and wait for response) from the com port and do real-time plot, and the main thread also need to access the same com port (send command only), so that to adjust the temperature sometime. if there is no protection, the thread A and the main thread may conflict and main thread will have serial write error sometime. Now I use two global values to temporally pause thread A, in main thread I have:

```
        stop_plot_heat_flag = 1
        while confirm_stop_plot_flag == 0:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        Class_heating1.start_heat_each(0,thermal_set)
        stop_plot_heat_flag,confirm_stop_plot_flag = 0,0
```

in thread A I have:

```
    if  stop_plot_heat_flag == 1: 
        confirm_stop_plot_flag = 1
    elif stop_plot_heat_flag == 0:
        inquire_thermal_data()
```

The above code works, but I think this is a common problem, and python should have some neat ways to handle this (main thread is priority), otherwise if I have many threads want to talk to the same com port, too many global variables to handle.

**Update:**
According to Frank comments, I use

```
lock.acquire()
...
lock.release()
```

in both threads, so far so good, I will continually monitor to see whether it is stable

**Update 2:**
in very rare situations (much better than before), it still have the conflict after lock.acquire(), I added time.sleep(0.1) after lock.acquire(),let's see whether we still have problems.

Comment: Is this just a mutual exclusion problem?  Use a lock.

Comment: Regardless of what programming language you use, what you are trying to do is a bad idea. Far better to have only one thread deal with serial port I/O and its issues, and then pass the data in messages to other threads.

Comment: @sawdust for example, both thread A and B pass the message to thread C (which deal with I/O as you mention), then in thread C how to sort the messages from thread A and thread B?  I was thinking some data structure such as queue, but hard to implement

Comment: @FrankYellin, thanks, so far so good, I am wondering if thread A does 'lock. acquire()' early then thread B, then the program in thread B just be paused until thread A execute 'lock.release()', no way for thread B commands lost,  am I right?

Comment: If you're concerned about commands being lost I'd also look at queues which are not hard to implement with built-in queue module. See https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-thread-queue/ for example

Comment: Seems like @Paul has supplied a method to use for message queues between Python threads. Why would "*thread C how to sort the messages*" when they simply have to be transmitted via serial port to the "*thermal board*"? Thread C needs just a single queue. Each message could have a reply attribute: (a) no reply expected, (b) wait for reply (i.e. suspend xmit until reply received). If responses from "*thermal board*" can be sorted by content, then each type of response can be put on the appropriate thread's queue. Else the original 'wait for reply' should have a thread's queue ID for return.